# VBA userform to copy pdfs from selected folder locations

Tags: excel, vba, userform

We import a CSV file into excel from Creo, this is our Bill of materials, We create the drawing PDF's and DXF's and save them in two 'MASTER' folders. When issuing the drawings to a manufacturer we must copy every individual drawing to a separate folder before sending.

The solution I am working on is to use a userform to select the 'copyfrom' location and 'copyto' location, on the 'run' command button, a sub should copy the files across.

I have the used the copy code by entering the folder locations in the Sub routine, but i need to allow other users to choose other files. The userform is adding the folder locations to the specific textboxes, but the next sub routine to copy the pdfs will not work.

I think it may be the textbox value is not recorded?

As a side I would also like to return the number of moved PDF's as part of the message in the Message box once the routine has completed. This may be different to the number of used cells in column B

The part number of the drawing will always be in column B

I haven't created the DXF option yet, but it will be very similar to the PDF one if i can get it to work

Any and all help much appreciated.

```
Private Sub cmdclose_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub copyfromcmd_Click()

Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String

Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
    '.InitialFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename()
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    copyfromtb.Value = sItem

Set fldr = Nothing


End Sub

Private Sub copytocmd_Click()

Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem2 As String

Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
    '.InitialFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename()
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem2 = .SelectedItems(1)

End With
NextCode:
GetFolder = sItem2
copytotb.Value = sItem2

Set fldr = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub runcmd_Click()
  Dim R As Range
  Dim SourcePath As String, DestPath As String, FName As String


  'Setup source and dest path (Note: must have a trailing backslash!)
  SourcePath = Me.copyfromtb.Value
  DestPath = Me.copytotb.Value

  'Visit each used cell in column B
  For Each R In Range("B1", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
   'Search the file with the file mask from the cell (Note: can contain                 wildcards like *.xls)
    FName = Dir(SourcePath & R.Value & ".pdf")
    'Loop while files found
    Do While FName <> ""
      'Copy the file
      FileCopy SourcePath & FName, DestPath & FName
      'Search the next file
      FName = Dir()
    Loop
  Next

  MsgBox ("PDF's Copied")
End Sub
```

Expected Results:

When the Copy Files command button is clicked, the pdf files from part numbers listed in column B will be copied from the first folder location to the second folder location.

If the entries are blank a message should appear which will request folder location are selected

Once the PDF's have been moved a message should appear to tell the user  the number of files which have been copied.

Actual Results:

The folder location is being entered into the required textbox, but the PDF's are not being copied over

[image: PDF Copy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  dim counter as integer
  counter = 0

  'Visit each used cell in column B
  For Each R In Range("B1", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
   'Search the file with the file mask from the cell (Note: can contain                 wildcards like *.xls)
    FName = Dir(SourcePath & R.Value & ".pdf")
    'Loop while files found
    Do While FName <> ""
      counter = counter + 1
      'Copy the file
      FileCopy SourcePath & FName, DestPath & FName
      'Search the next file
      FName = Dir()
    Loop
  Next

  MsgBox (counter & " PDF's Copied")
```

good luck

Answer (score 1):

I just realized my error

I need to add the trailing backslash!

```
  SourcePath = Me.copyfromtb.Value
  DestPath = Me.copytotb.Value
```

Changed to

```
  SourcePath = copyfromtb.Value & "\"
  DestPath = copytotb.Value & "\"
```

Still having issues with counting the number of moved files and adding that value to the message box at the end

Comment: hi. this line FName = Dir() what is supose to do ?

Comment: Im not exactly sure, the code is working so i thought it best not to mess with it

Comment: well, in the loop     Do While FName <> "" u can put a counter, like counter+=1, to count all files.... and for the message u can put  MsgBox (counter & " PDF's Copied").

Comment: Thanks Luis, would you be able to post a code for that counter option?